# Dynamically change text of button with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I have a dropdown list with 5 elements which are displayed inside the button when pressed. 
Right now, the button gets the value of selected tab but I want it to have a default text before this value; this text should be "Filter by:" value. And I also need that caret to be displayed...Any ideas how I can get this working?

HTML:

```
<div class='filtering_options dropdown'>
  <button class="btn bet-filter btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Filter by:
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu CHECK-HEIGHT" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href='#brzn/yolo/all' class='btn btn-filter all' data-filter='all'>{{translate 'bets_filter_all'}}</a></li>
    <li><a href='#brzn/yolo/open' class='btn btn-filter open' data-filter='open'>{{translate 'bets_filter_open'}}</a></li>
    <li><a href='#brzn/yolo/closed' class='btn btn-filter closed' data-filter='closed'>{{translate 'bets_filter_closed'}}</a></li>
    <li><a href='#brzn/yolo/pending' class='btn btn-filter pending' data-filter='pending'>{{translate 'bets_filter_ended'}}</a></li>
    <li><a href='#brzn/yolo/resolved' class='btn btn-filter resolved' data-filter='resolved'>{{translate 'bets_filter_resolved'}}</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS with coffeescript:

```
  filter: (filter)->
    # set default values for the filter
    if _.isEmpty(filter)
      filter = @default_filter
    if filter.dir
      filter.dir = parseInt(filter.dir) || 0
    if !(filter.status in ['all', 'open', 'closed', 'pending', 'resolved'])
      filter.status = 'all'
    prev_filter = @filter_options
    @filter_options = _.extend({}, @default_filter, filter)
    if _.isEqual(@filter_options, prev_filter)
      return
    @update_comments(@filter_options)
    @$('.btn-filter.active').not(".btn-filter.#{filter.status}").removeClass('active')
    @$(".btn-filter.#{filter.status}").addClass('active')
    @$(".bet-filter").text(filter.status)
```

Comment: so there really are people using coffeescript...

Comment: Yeah github. Have you heard of them?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by myself:

1. Created a new translation for 'Filter by'
2. Concatenate this translation with value

`@$(".bet-filter").text((@app.translate('filter_by')) + (filter.status))`